# how to provide functionalities for buttons in flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

i am new to flex. I want to create some buttons and when v click on that button, it should open some images. how to give this functionality in flex builder 3. Thanks for ur time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example if it helps.
The important thing is embedding the image before you use it.Another way of embedding is inline in the mx:Image tag.Please be careful with the path to the location of the image.

> ```
>        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>          <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
> <mx:Script>
>     <![CDATA[
>         /*in the source put the absolute path(like directory:/folder/image.gif) or the relative path (../image.gif where ../ is your project directory )to the location of your image
>          */
>         [Embed (source="../src/assets/images/image.gif")]
>          [Bindable]
>          //this variable of type Class is used to refer to the aboveimage..
>          public var img:Class;
>          public function buttonClickHandler():void{
>           if(image.visible)
>           image.visible = false;
>           else
>           image.visible = true;
>           }
>           ]]>
> </mx:Script>
> <mx:Image source="{img}" visible="false" id="image"/>
> <mx:Button x="172" y="225" label="Button" id="button" click="buttonClickHandler()"/>
> </mx:Application>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

hi have a click handler for the button. in the function of click handler handle displaying of image by switching visibilities.have the image embedded in the design before itself. then play with its visibilities on button click.

Comment: i want to get images from hard disk into swf file. is it possible? thanks again..!

Comment: copy the image and keep it in the project folder in the workspace.from the project folder you can embed it...see the below example of himanshu how he has embeded it...same way

Comment: thats great. Thank you very much. It is very useful for me and now i am able to do such kind of things. One more thing i have to know. that is- can i play a sound in background when the user is able to view the image. I am planning to show the images one after the other with 'next' button and i will play the appropriate sound. Any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

try going through the examples here.explains about all kind of asset embedding,including sound
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=04_OO_Programming_09.html